# I want to append to a new list , only the tuples in which the third element is the same with the third element of the first tuple

Tags: python, iteration, tuples

After a sort to a list of tuples, for example:

```
jen =  (34,54,15) , (34,65,15), (34, 78,89) ...
```

I am trying to append to a new list only the tuples which contain the third element of the first tuple for instance the new list must contain only:

```
(34,54,15) 
(34,65,15)
```

Here is my pseudocode:

```
   Salvation_array = []
    For lines in  jen:
    Num = 0
    If jen[0] [:-2] = Num:
    Salvation_array.append(Num)
```

I am really confused with this can you help , suggest something?

Comment: For clarification, does "tuples which contain the third element" mean "the third element must be the same" or "they must contain the 3rd element _anywhere_"?

Comment: what should be the output if you have this `(34,54,15) , (34,65,15), (34, 15,89)`

Comment: No it cannot be anywere @Rawing.  Only compares the third element of the first typle.

Comment: @danidee The output should be (34,54,15) , (34,65,15). Only this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the requirements correctly, this should do what you want:

```
jen = (34,54,15), (34,65,15), (34, 78,89)

salvation_army = [j for j in jen if j[2] == jen[0][2]]

print(salvation_army)

# Output:
# [(34, 54, 15), (34, 65, 15)]
```

It's similar to @Harsh's answer but uses list comprehension rather than `filter`. (This is a matter of taste.)

Something more along the lines of what you were trying to do:

```
salvation_army = []
desired_value = jen[0][2]

for line in jen:
    if line[2] == desired_value:
        salvation_army.append(line)
```

Comment: nice answer, I should start using list comprehension more !

Comment: OMG you did what you want with one line of code. very impressing , thanks.  I cant imagine how dangerous someone can be if he knows python.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `filter` method easily.

In one liner `filter` call:

```
array1 = [(34,54,15) , (34,65,15), (34, 78,89)]
array2 = filter(lambda element: element[2] == array[0][2], array)
print array2
[(34, 54, 15), (34, 65, 15)]
```

You can check the documentation of `filter` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter).
So, basically what `filter( some_function(e) , array)` does it it iterates through each element `e` of array and test if it satisfies some condition. This check is done using the call `some_function(e)`. If that function returns `True`, the element `e` is kept, otherwise not.

Also, since you mentioned that you are python novice, I guess you might not know about `lambda` in python. So basically can take them as one liner nameless functions. You can think of following to be equivalent: `lambda x: print x` and `def printit(x): print x;` You can check about `lambda` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the tips and the guidelines. Very helpful indeed